# Win8 IRC app problems

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, irc

I've been trying to write an IRC client app for windows 8. I've hit some problem. I've started from this tutorial for pytho: http://oreilly.com/pub/h/1968
Resulting into the following code (for python 3.3). It manages to connect to a server, get recognized and logged on until I shut the client down.

```
server = "irc.location.net"
from socket import *

def main():
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((server, 6667))
    readbuffer = ""
    s.send("NICK testIRC\r\n".encode())
    s.send("USER testIRC irc.location.net welcome :Test_IRC\r\n".encode())

    while 1:
        readbuffer = readbuffer + s.recv(1024).decode()
        temp = readbuffer.split("\n")
        readbuffer = temp.pop()

        for line in temp:
            line = line.rstrip();
            tokens = line.split(' ');

            if (tokens[0] == "PING"): 
                print("Got: %s\n" % line);
                response = "PONG %s\r\n" % tokens[1];
                s.send(response.encode())
                print("Sending: %s\n\n" % response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main();
```

Then I tried to port it to C# (.NET 4.5) and the result can be seen below. This code however does not give the same result as the Python code.
I think the following could be happening but I'm not sure: the server doesn't recognize the encoding (which I think is strange). To make everything even more strange, I get 1 ping which contains something that looks like a key (some hexadecimal value) to which I off course respond with a pong.
After that first ping I receive nothing, also I'm not listed in the users list.
But other then an encoding problem, I can't think of anything. Can one of you spot an error in my code? Thanks a lot in advance.

```
StreamSocket ss = new StreamSocket();
await ss.ConnectAsync(new HostName(server_address), 6667.ToString());

DataWriter dw = new DataWriter(ss.OutputStream);
DataReader dr = new DataReader(ss.InputStream);
dr.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;

// Text related stuff
byte[] bytes;

// register
bytes = enc.GetBytes("NICK testIRC\r\n"); // enc is of type Encoding and is created as an UTF8Encoding.
dw.WriteBytes(bytes);
bytes = enc.GetBytes("USER testIRC irc.location.net welcome :Test_IRC\r\n");
dw.WriteBytes(bytes);
await dw.StoreAsync();
await dw.FlushAsync();

int ping_count = 0;

while (true)
{
    await dr.LoadAsync(512);
    string msg = dr.ReadString(dr.UnconsumedBufferLength);

    string[] lines = msg.Split(new string[]{"\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach(string line in lines)
    {
        string cmd = line.TrimEnd('\r');

        if (cmd.StartsWith("PING "))
        {
            ping_count++;

            string[] tokens = cmd.Split(' ');

            // Create response
            string response = "PONG " + tokens[1];
            bytes = enc.GetBytes(response);

            dw.WriteBytes(bytes);
            dw.StoreAsync();
            dw.FlushAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you suspect it's an encoding issue: what happens when you use ASCII instead of UTF-8?

Comment: What is `DataWriter`? What happens when you use `BinaryWriter` instead? Also, writing data does not mean the data is "sent" (it's often buffered). Make sure you flush the stream to ensure it's sent.

Comment: @Jeff E: using ASCII didn't change anything unfortunately. In the windows8 app runtime, there is no ASCIIEncoding class, so I had to write a function to convert everything to ASCII, I basically did this: foreach(char c in str) {buffer[index] = (byte)(c & 0xff); index++; }buffer[str.length] = 0; Dai, Datawriter:[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR208154) , if you've read the code you see that I call both .StoreAsync AND .FlushAsync, also, I added await to the last calls to StoreAsync and FlushAsync.

Comment: Just checked what the encoding is that is used in pythons .encode() function. On my system it's UTF-8.

Comment: Found the problem, the PONG didn't end with "\r\n".